# Excel 2010: Use icon list for custom list

Tags: microsoft-excel-2010, conditional-formatting

I want to utilize the Icon Sets for a custom list.

Take this list:

```
Low
Medium
High
Very High
```

This is the order of the custom list. I want, for instance, to use the "4 Traffic Lights" on that list.
So Low shows the black circle, Medium the light grey, High the light red, Very High the strong red.

Is this possible?

Comment: Can you provide more details?  Do you have a table or something with a row of data and you want this at the end or beginning in a cell to summarize the overall importance?  Do you plan to use this in a later step?

Comment: I have a bunch of records (rows), where 1 of the fields (columns) is "Severity".

Each record input will be have a value of Low, Medium, High or Very High.

I want each cell in this field (column) to display an icon in that particular cell based on the order in the custom list (so you could say that conceptually it is 1 = Low, 2 = Medium, etc.) I could of course just use numbers and write a legend, but I would prefer using the actual words.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is what I ended up doing:

I ended up using values of 1;-1;0 (and got rid of Very High as classification).

Then I Custom formatted the cells to: "High";"Low";"Medium"

Custom formatting:
[image: Custom formatting]

By doing this the values displays the text instead (so 1 displays "High").

Then I simply added an Icon Set to these cells:

[image: End result]

Answer (score 0):

Assuming your trigger values are in Column D, use this nested formula:

```
=IF(D3="Low",1,IF(D3="Medium",11,IF(D3="High",21,IF(D3="Very High",31,0))))
```

Then, set up your conditional formatting setting the icon colours based on the value returned by the formula.
 e.g. black >= 0, Green >= 10, Red >= 20, Bright Red >= 30